# Is there a way to add child rows for an existing row in jquery datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a huge table with 60 columns and 200 rows in a datatable. Some columns are fixed in left side. Below is what i tried.

```
var childRows = getChildRows(id); //Gives a html string with multiple rows.
var dTable = $('#dataTable').Datatable(); // Api functions.
var row = dTable.row(this); // To get the parent row element from datatable.
row.child($(childRows));
```

Here the problem is it adds the child rows to the right table but those are not reflected in the fixed columns. Any solution is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data in a JSFiddle to make it easier to answer your question, it's hard to imagine what your code should do and does not do.

Comment: I will make it and keep you posted.